# How to return a pandas Series from an inner function

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

This script is a simplified version of what I have as its too long to put here. I have tried to include all necessary information.

```
class data():

    def collect_data(self):
        def reader(n):
            self.df[n] = self.join_data(self.EO[n].real)
        # for i in (1, 2, 4, 6): reader(i)

    def join_data(self, func1)
        do stuff
        return self.df # is a Series

    def data_excel(self)
        self.df[1].to_excel(......) #line 1
        self.df[2].to_excel(......)
        self.df[4].to_excel(......)
        self.df[6].to_excel(......)
```

```
#on line 1
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

The Series contains chunks of "strings and numeric" data where each chunk starts with row index 0.

```
print(dfEO_RI.head(1).to_dict())

{0: '*amplitude'}
{0: '*amplitude'}
{0: '*amplitude'}
{0: '*amplitude'}
```

The function join_data successfully returns a Series but I dont know how to correctly pass it through the function collect_data and subsequently to function data_excel

**Desired Output**

4 Series data output to excel

Comment: Why `df[1].to_excel(...)` and not `self.df[1].to_excel(...)`?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. Corrected.

Comment: Update your post with the output of `print(data_instance.df.head(5).to_dict())`

Comment: I found a way. I created another instance attribute 'test' then I wrote df[n].test for both the collect_data and data_excel functions.